# Switch Div on button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a carousel like effect on `div`s such thta when i click on a but, the next `div` displays and the previous one `fadeOut`. Below is my code

```
var oCurImage = $(".webTut div.current");
var oNxtImage = $(oCurImage).next();
var leftBtn = $('.tutLeft'), rightBtn = $('.tutRight');

$(rightBtn).click(function() {
      oCurImage.fadeOut().removeClass('current');
      oNxtImage.fadeIn().addClass('current').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);

      if (oNxtImage.length == 0) {
          oNxtImage = $(".webTut div:first-child");
      }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="webTut">
  <span class="tutBtn"><a class="tutLeft"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a><a class="tutRight"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></span>
  <div class="current">
  <img src="images/egold.png">
  <h1>cname</h1>
  <h3>Welcome to nigeriaeexport.com</h3>
  <p>Your one stop platform for everything export</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background: #fff;"></div>
  <div style="background: #dd0d0d;"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.webTut div {
    width: 60%;
    height: 80%;
    background: #28bc88;
    margin: 6.5% auto 0 auto;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    /*854 x 720*/
}
.webTut div.current {
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The thing is i have used this same method with `setInterval` for an image slider but here when i click on the button the first time, it shows the next div (the white one) but when i click again, it doesn't change to the next `div` (the red one #dd0d0d). What could be the issue and how do i fix. Thanks.

Comment: You're not updating the element oCurImage points to.  It's always pointing to whatever it was originally before the click event.  Same for oNxtImage if the length of it isn't 0

Answer (score 1):

Once you click on right anchor tag you should change value of `oCurImage` and `oNxtImage` and for getting first div inside div with class `.webTut` you should use `$(".webTut div:first");`

You can run below code snippet.

```js
var oCurImage = $(".webTut div.current");
var oNxtImage = $(oCurImage).next();
var leftBtn = $('.tutLeft');
var rightBtn = $('.tutRight');

$(rightBtn).click(function() {
      oCurImage.fadeOut().removeClass('current');
    if (oNxtImage.length == 0) {
          oNxtImage = $(".webTut div:first");
      }
      oNxtImage.fadeIn().addClass('current').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);
   oCurImage = $(".webTut div.current");
   oNxtImage = $(oCurImage).next();
});
```

```css
.webTut div {
    width: 60%;
    height: 80%;
    background: #28bc88;
    margin: 6.5% auto 0 auto;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    /*854 x 720*/
}
.webTut div.current {
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="webTut">
  <span class="tutBtn"><a class="tutLeft">left</a> <br/><br/><a class="tutRight">right</i></a></span>
  <div class="current">
   <h1>cname</h1>
   <h3>Welcome to nigeriaeexport.com</h3>
   <p>Your one stop platform for everything export</p>
  </div>
  <div style="background: #fff;">First Div</div>
  <div style="background: #dd0d0d;">Second Div</div>
 </div>
```